# Actualizar subdocumento embebidos - mongoDB - nodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una api rest y me encontré con la dificultad de poder
actualizar el atributo de una imagen. Estoy usando para las imágenes
el servicio de cloudinary.

Mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
const UsuarioSchema = Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es obligatorio']
    },
    cedula: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'La cédula es obligatoria'],
        unique: true
    },
     movimientos_cuenta: [{ 
        importe: {
            type: Number
        },
        img: {
            type: String
        },
        concepto: {
            type: String,
            emun: ['DEBE', 'PAGO']
        }
    }]  
});
```

En el llamado de la api:

```
{{url}}/api/uploads/usuarios/61fc71528f3076f7275db4f5
```

envio el nombre de la colección mas el uid del usuario, la cosa es que debo encontrar dentro del array el movimiento que deseo actualizar.

Realicé un método y otra ruta para actualizar las imágenes, que es el siguiente:

```
const actualizarImagenCloudinary = async(req, res = response ) => {
    const { id, coleccion } = req.params;

    let modelo;
    
    switch ( coleccion ) {
        case 'usuarios':
            modelo = await Usuario.findById(id); 

            if ( !modelo ) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: `No existe un usuario con el id ${ id }`
                });
            }
        
        break;

        case 'productos':
            modelo = await Producto.findById(id);
            if ( !modelo ) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: `No existe un producto con el id ${ id }`
                });
            }
        
        break;
    
        default:
            return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Validar'});
}
    if ( modelo.img ) {
        const nombreArr = modelo.img.split('/');
        const nombre    = nombreArr[ nombreArr.length - 1 ];
        const [ public_id ] = nombre.split('.');
        cloudinary.uploader.destroy( public_id );
    }


    const { tempFilePath } = req.files.archivo
    const { secure_url } = await cloudinary.uploader.upload( tempFilePath );
    modelo.img = secure_url;

    await modelo.save();

    res.json(modelo);

}
```

Por ejemplo en el modelo de productos esta solución funciona perfectamente porque el atributo es del documento en si mismo, pero en el caso de usuarios el atributo que debo modificar esta dentro de un array y no estoy encontrando una solución para esto.